# Is it possible to have 2 different pubsub to direct to a single cloudfunction?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have project A and Project B.I  have created sink,pub/sub,cloudfunction in Project A.I want logs from logging to be transferred to bigquery dataset.So I filtered the logs ,created a sink with those logs ,created a Cloudfunction to transfer the logs to bigquery.It was successful.

I want logs from Project B to be directed to the CloudFunction in Project A.I created another sink and topic(Pub/Sub) in project B and another subscription(Pub/Sub) in Project A and  selected topic from Project B that I created.

So I have two subscriptions in Project A.In one sub,I have logs from Project A and another sub,I have logs from Project B .I want both the subscription messages to be directed to the same CloudFunction.

2 subscriptions from 2 different projects as shown below:

[image]

Issue is I am able to select only one pub/sub in CloudFunction in Project A.
[image]

Is there any way to get logs from two subscriptions in one CloudFunction?or any other alternative?Please let me know if the question is not clear.I will add more explanation and screenshots if required.

Comment: Even if this isn't possible on the configuration level, can't you make a single function and `export` a Cloud Functions binding for it twice?

Comment: I did not get your point..could you please explain me more about CF binding twice

Comment: Leaving aside for a moment a desire to invoke a cloud function from two differnet topics... I am not sure that one can trigger (push) a cloud function from a topic of a different (from the cloud function) project - see issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173534853  I think documentation is very clear about it: "Cloud Functions can be triggered by messages published to Pub/Sub topics in the same Cloud project as the function." - see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub

Comment: As Frank suggested - can you deploy the same cloud function (as code and configuration) but with different names (as names are to be unique) and different triggers (one topic for the first deployment, and another for the second deployment)?

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scene, when you create a backend function triggered by cloud pubsub topic, cloud function will create a new subscription for that topic. So you have a mapping 1 to 1 with the subscription. A workaround, in your case, is to have 2 PUSH subscriptions, with one endpoint, pointing to your HTTP function.

**Edit 1**

Below a step by step solution using push subscription, posting messages to HTTP function.

1. Create a HTTP Cloud Function (CF) triggered only with HTTPS and required authentication. More details can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http)
2. Once the function is successfully deployed, it can be reached through a URL following this pattern : `https://<REGION>-<PROJECT_ID>.cloudfunctions.net/<FUNCTION_NAME>`
3. For your topic, in any project, the same as you CF or other, create a PUSH subscription:

- Push endpoint: the URL of your CF
- Check Enable autentication
- Choose a Service Account (SA)
- Audience : the URL of your CF

4. Give the SA which can be in any project, the `Cloud Functions Invoker` role on. your Cloud Function (PERMISSIONS tab in your cloud functions screen)
5. Give service-{PROJECT_NUMBER}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com the `Service Account Token Creator` role, where {PROJECT_NUMBER} is the GCP project that contains the subscription.

Below a simple HTTP cloud function implementation in Python:

```py
import base64
import json


def handle_pubsub_push_subscription_message(request):
    envelope = json.loads(request.data.decode('utf-8'))
    payload = base64.b64decode(envelope['message']['data']).decode('utf-8')
    print(f"payload: {payload}")
    # Returning any 2xx status indicates successful receipt of the message.
    return "SUCCESS", 200
```

And an example of a command to deploy the HTT function:

```sh
gcloud functions deploy <FUNCTION_NAME> \
--entry-point handle_pubsub_push_subscription_message \
--project <PROJECT_ID> \
--region <REGION> \
--memory 128Mi \
--runtime python39 \
--trigger-http \
--security-level=secure-always
```

Comment: https://d4d1290519676f29baf13a7bf18a25bf-dot-r680fc79ac61f7e68p-tp.appspot.com/_ah/push-handlers/pubsub/projects/sampleproject-mmhr/topics/dialogflow?pubsub_trigger=true ---this is the push endpoint that subscription has when its getting created. Here topic name. in the url  is dialogflow(Topic from the project A).When I create another subscription in Project A and select topic from Project B,do I need to change the topic name in the url?If I need to change,will this overallmethod work?

Comment: The push endpoint you shared is automatically created for the background pubsub function you created. What you need is an HTTP function and a manually created push subscription whose push endpoint is the HTTP cloud function URL.  I edited my response to provide you with a more detailed solution. As you can see the push endpoint of your subscription will follow HTTP functions URL pattern : `https://<REGION>-<PROJECT_ID>.cloudfunctions.net/<FUNCTION_NAME>`.